# Dependency Management in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, dependency-management

I am new to AndroidStudio and Gradle. I have an android project AppA which depends on a android library module LibA. LibA depends on another android library module LibB. I declared module dependencies in corresponding build.gradle files.

```
    compile project(':LibModuleName')
```

Everything works fine as expected. But when I try to use the .aar file generated by Lib A in another application project AppB, my app crashes due to ClassNotFoundException. Classes in LibB cant be found.

Why LibB is not getting added to .aar of LibA ? Is there any solution to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You must add the LibB dependency to AppB also.  This is currently how transitive dependencies are working with Gradle in Android Studio.

Another possibility is to try

```
   compile project(':LibA') {
      transitive=true
   }
```

Comment: I get could not set unknown property 'transitive' for project if I try this